# Adjust view size inside viewpager, make up for tab height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm having a bit of a problem with a ViewPager that loads fragments for each of its three tabs. Inside the first fragment, there's a vertical LinearLayout with a ListView. The list view is dynamically loaded with items, but when the item count exceeds the screen size, it doesn't scroll to show the rest of the items.

My guess is that the fragment (which is setup to match the parent's height) is pushed down by the tabview in the parent layout (a CoordinatorLayout inside a DrawerLayout). How can I make up for the TabView height in the ViewPager or force the fragment to limit it's size to the remaining screen height?

Here's an image of the app:
[image: See the OS's scroll delimiter being barely shown behind the navigation bar]

Here's my code:

### Activity_Home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

### fragment_account.xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/accounts_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mycompany.myapp.fragments.AccountsFragment" />
```

Comment: No, in the fragment layout there should only be the listview and its height set to match_parent. No extra linearlayout or scrollview

Comment: I changed the fragment's XML to contain the ListView as root element, but the issue persists. Still overflowing below the actionbar

Comment: Oh, you mean you want that the tabs and actionbar scroll with the listview??

Comment: No, see, in the image above, there's one list item left to appear on screen. I made my best to show the bottom scroll delimiter, but most of it is hidden behind the navigation bar

Comment: the only thing i see  that may cause the problem is  android:padding in listview, and there is 4 of them.

Comment: The horizontal and vertical margins are set to 0dp :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96285/discussion-between-ashkan-ghodrat-and-niche).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the issue by removing the app:layout_scrollFlags attribute from the toolbar. I figure the app was waiting for me to scroll to hide the toolbar, which would give the fragment the missing height adjustment.

Comment: This answer worked for me! Simple and effective. It is a real shame that this line of xml markup is added automatically by the Android Studio Wizard and cause what I would call 'unexpected behavior'. Thank you for this answer. It was a big help.

Answer (score 0):

remove the **app:layout_scrollFlags**

```xml
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
```