# In android default tabbed activity, fragment doesn't fit the screen as height and actionBar is movable

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout, androiddesignsupport

I simply created a `TabbedActivity` on `Android Studio 1.5.1`. I didn't change any code but `Fragment` doesn't fit the screen as height and `ActionBar` is movable.

`Views` that at the bottom are invisible. I need to move `ActionBar` up to see bottom views.(See the video please: [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ow_iinyG-1Q) )

So, i have 2 questions:

1. After i put `ListView` in `Fragment`, how can i move `ActionBar` up smoothly when user scrolls `ListView`? (WhatsApp and Viber are using this technique)

2.How can i prevent `ActionBar` from moving and align `Fragment` to bottom of screen?

Here is the `Main Activity` that android created:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
        }
        return null;
      }
   }
}
```

Activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.eren.siiilllfdjfds.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**EDIT:** [image]

I think i need to change this line of container:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

**EDIT2:** When i delete the code that i mention in 1. edit, fragment align to bottom but start of fragment align to top of screen, i mean fragment goes behind `actionBar`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust view size inside viewpager, make up for tab height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33944100/adjust-view-size-inside-viewpager-make-up-for-tab-height)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After i put `ListView` in fragment, how can i move `ActionBar` up smoothly
>   when user scrolls listView? (WhatsApp and Viber are using this
>   technique)

First of all, better/or let's say ***you have to*** use `RecyclerView` with:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

As mentioned here:(Added in the below)

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#responding-to-scroll-events

And about that design like `WhatsApp`, i used below codes:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_18dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> When i delete the code that i mention in 1. edit, fragment align to
>   bottom but start of fragment align to top of screen, i mean fragment
>   goes behind actionBar.

**You must add:**

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

For using the contents **under** the `AppBarLayout` and fixing everything.

**See**: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#responding-to-scroll-events

Which says:

> **Note:** AppBarLayout currently expects to be the first child nested within a CoordinatorLayout according to the official Google docs.
>
> Next, **we need to define an association between the `AppBarLayout` and
>   the `View` that will be scrolled.** Add an `app:layout_behavior` to a
>   R`ecyclerView` or any other `View` capable of `nested scrolling` such as
>   `NestedScrollView`. The support library contains a special string
>   `resource @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` that maps to
>   `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior`, which is used to notify the
>   `AppBarLayout` when scroll events occur on this particular view. The
>   behavior must be established on the view that triggers the event.

**Edit:** And if you need to pin the `Toolbar` there, just use:

```
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
```

Finally:

```
       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
```

Comment: thanks for answer! I will try this. But what about my 2. question?

Comment: We are using a question with one thread in StackOverFlow btw, try to remove this and see: `android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"` the answer is you have to use that `app:layout_behavior`, if it didn't work(it should work btw) tell me to try it out myself.

Comment: `@dimen/appbar_padding_top` is 8dp. It was not enough, i needed `100dp` to offset top of fragment and it is not a good practice because `actionBar` is still movable. Still i couldn't find a way to fix `actionBar` and fit fragment to workspace.

Btw thanks a lot for your attention and detailed answer. I will accept your answer after i try and first i need to find an answer for 2. question.

Comment: Can you paste your current code with your try somewhere? i really enjoy that if i can fix that too because my answer was correct.

Comment: `<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="100dp"
        />`

as you said, i removed `app:layout_behavior` and writed the `paddingTop` ... i hope that i understood correctly

Comment: Remove that padding top and just add the code i've sended in my answer, please paste all the codes on pastebin or something like that.

Comment: doesn't work...in dimens: `<dimen name="appbar_padding_top">8dp</dimen>`...So, as i saod 8dp is not enough

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103222/discussion-between-eren130-and-linx64).

Answer (score 11):

I am running Android 2, so I am not sure whether this applies for 1.5.

Inside main activity xml, as being auto generated by Android there's Toolbar widget:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
```

When I removed this line:

```
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

...all problems gone.

The screen does not scroll anymore and the screen height is calculated correctly so you get to see all views inside whatever you were displaying on (fragment or activity)

So I would concentrate on investigating that line:

```
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

Comment: This answer worked for me! Simple and effective. It is a real shame that this line of xml markup is added automatically by the Android Studio Wizard and cause what I would call 'unexpected behavior'. Thank you for this answer. It was a big help.